# Display a new GameOver view controller from storyboard when collision is detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I am slowly making my first iOS game & have run into an issue. I am trying to get my game to go to a "game over" screen which i have made using a view controller & label in storyboard (along with my other two view controllers, one for start screen which works & one for current game).

Here is my collision function that is called when collision has been detected. Commented is what i want to do.

```
func collision(Bee:SKSpriteNode, Player:SKSpriteNode) {
println("GAME OVER")
println(leftOrRight)
// Call game over view controller from storyboard
}
```

Can anyone help me do this ? Or if this is wrong method of achieving a game over screen, point me in the right direction? :)

Thanks.

Comment: did you make a segue from the gameviewcontroller to the gameovercontroller?

Comment: No i'm not sure what that means exactly. I have looked online for a guide to follow but have been unsuccessful

Comment: how did u move from the start screen to gameviewcontroller?

Comment: read both tutorials on using storyboards http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a weak property inside the GameScene called `gameViewController`.

```
weak var gameViewController : GameViewController? = nil
```

Then assign the property before you present the scene inside the `GameViewController` `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))

    scene.gameViewController = self
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Create a segue with a unique name from `GameViewController` to `GameOverViewController`. Then inside `collision` function.

```
func collision(Bee:SKSpriteNode, Player:SKSpriteNode) {
    println("GAME OVER")
    println(leftOrRight)
    self.gameViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToGameOverController",
        sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create GameOver Scene and present that scene instead of performing segue to show another view controller.

```
func collision(Bee:SKSpriteNode, Player:SKSpriteNode) {
println("GAME OVER")
println(leftOrRight)

//create GameOverScene here, then present it
let mainSKView = self.view as SKView!
let gameOverScene: GameOverScene = GameOverScene()

mainSKView.presentScene(gameOverScene)
}
```

- EDIT

You can test the work of this solution by following these steps:

1. Create an SpriteKit Scene file (.sks file), just to test so you don't need to draw anything in that scene this time
2. Create a subclass of SKScene named GameOverScene, once again, let the class empty, just for test, like this

`import SpriteKit 
class GameOverScene: SKScene {}`

3. in Collision function call the gameoverScene like this:

`let mainSKView = self.view as SKView!
 let gameOverScene: GameOverScene! = GameOverScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene") 
mainSKView.presentScene(gameOverScene)`

Tell me if it does not work. Sorry for bad answer format, I can not insert my whole code in a block, and I dont know why. So stupid I am.

Comment: This kind of solution was my intention and is what I have tried previously, but with this code specifically I get a "Use of undeclared type "GameOverScene". How can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you get that error? in the class GameOverScene or in function collision(...). You have to create a SKScene subclass (class GameOverScene: SKScene) and draw corresponding .sks file. On collision function, you can create an instance of GameOverScene by unarchiveFromFile function (it is also the way you created and called GameScene from your ViewController)

Comment: I just made a new View Controller in the main.storyboard. I want to link it to that view controller I made.

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it out and tell me if it works for you

Comment: Thanks for the help, this makes sense but it chucks me a this error '2015-02-10 09:13:55.426 TestGame[777:7326044] -[SKEmitterNode _didMoveToView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff2c9306f80
2015-02-10 09:13:55.428 TestGame[777:7326044] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKEmitterNode _didMoveToView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff2c9306f80'

Comment: SKEmitterNode has no method named "didMoveToView". Is that you are trying to cast a SKEmitterNode into a SKScene ?

Comment: Okay I think I have it. How can I add a button in a .sks though?

Comment: you can add a SKSpriteNode (with image or color to make it look like a button and a name to distinguish buttons), and on the code of Scene, catch event touchesBegan and do what ever you want inside handler function